# Why does this FTP block read operation throw EOFError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ftp, readline

Can someone please explain why this block read operation would throw an EOFError?  The way I saw it, it would just end the block when the file was read completely.  What am I missing?  How can I fix it?  Thanks so much.

NOTE: I should mention that at times it runs fine and at others it throws the EOFError.  On the same file which is in the same location...

```
    Net::FTP.open(host=ftp.address, user='********', passwd='********') do |ftp|
      ftp.passive = true
      files = ftp.nlst('*')
      s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1')
      files.each do |file|
        ftp.getbinaryfile(file, file, 65536) # Copies file to /tmp
        UpdateVfile.loader(@company, file) # Process file from /tmp
        s3_file = file + Time.zone.now.strftime("-%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M.xls")
        obj = s3.bucket('mydatafeed').object(s3_file) # Build object in S3 bucket
        data = ''
        ftp.getbinaryfile(file, nil, 65536) do |block|  <== EOFError thrown here!
          data << block
        end
        obj.put(body: data) # Write it to S3
        ftp.delete(file) # Delete the file from FTP
      end
    end
```

Stack trace:

```
An EOFError occurred in background at 2015.11.23 :

  end of file reached
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:1112:in `readline'

  -------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:1112:in `readline'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:289:in `getline'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:300:in `getmultiline'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:318:in `getresp'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:351:in `block in sendcmd'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:349:in `sendcmd'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:394:in `makepasv'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:406:in `transfercmd'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:490:in `block (2 levels) in retrbinary'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:488:in `block in retrbinary'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:487:in `retrbinary'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:620:in `getbinaryfile'
  /app/lib/tasks/updates_vfile.rake:40:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

FTP debug_mode OUTPUT:

```
put: TYPE A
get: 200 Command TYPE okay.
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (75,101,155,12,5,165)
put: NLST *
get: 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
get: 226 Closing data connection.
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Command TYPE okay.
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (75,101,155,12,5,163)
put: RETR <filename redacted>
get: 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
get: 226 Transfer complete.
...output from update processing
put: PASV
rake aborted!
EOFError: end of file reached
```

Comment: `ftp.debug_mode = true` please enable it and try it

Comment: @RajarshiDas It's been added above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an FTP idle timeout.  Because UpdateVfile.loader is a long-running task, I left FTP alone for too long and it cratered with an EOFError.  Obviously, a timeout error would have been much better than such a nondescript failure that gave me worse than no diagnostic information.

If the loader was short, it worked.  For more intense updates, it took too long.  As I changed the source to try to diagnose and resolve the issue, the EOFError moved to the ftp.delete command, which made even less sense to me.

I found some discussions that hinted at this problem.  As a result, I changed my process to handle all of the FTP work before calling the loader.  This works reliably.  Otherwise, I'd either have to send periodic keep-alives or find a way to modify the timeout period.  Neither appears easy to accomplish.

I'd be happy if someone could explain to me why FTP would issue EOFError instead of a timeout error.  That's just not right and would lead anyone in totally the wrong direction, diagnostically.  Thanks...